# SQLConnection in DataModule

Tags: sql, database, delphi

I'm doing some test with my Tokyo (RTM). I just have a TForm and a DataModule, both create at the launch (datamodule before the form).

All is okay in Windows, my database is located to my harddrive.

I deploye it to Android with my database and application crash at the launch. I didnt see any of my showmessage in FormCreate event of the DataModule or the Form.

I copy my SQLConnection to the the MainForm, use this one instead of the one on the DataModule and all is ok.

Didnt understand why, any idea ? Thats same component and no more code.

Comment: please add your failure stack trace

Comment: If your dataset is streamed with Active = True, it may be related to the problem here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46601409/issue-with-tfdquery-on-a-form-connecting-to-a-datamodule/46611922#46611922

Comment: @MartynA, déjà vu :) There's more about keeping FireDAC objects active. Even in VCL application there are some issues when you keep the FireDAC objects active at design time. I'd highly recommend to keep them inactive (it can be as easy as that linked connection is created after the command object which wants to use a non-existing component; but that is just a wild guess, haven't checked that). I hope those _"Active"_ properties are published just for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Thanks, will check the stack trace and my Connection is inactive, I set it to true in the FormCreate.

Comment: @Bosshoss, when you'll be at that, check if the connection object exists at that time.

Comment: @Victoria:  Indeed, & it does seem to be related to the FDConnection.   I've just posted a minor update to my answer to the other q.  But I'm not aware of the VCL issues, so please feel free to elaborate ...

Comment: @MartynA, I remember there was an issue with kind of _"connection already opened"_ when I was using the Connection Editor, even if `Connected` property was set to `False` after Connection Editor was closed (just used the `Test` button). Setting `Connected` property to `True` and back to `False` _fixed_ that. Have no Delphi by hand now (and haven't stepped into your excellent post about how to reproduce the issue).

Comment: I see some issues on jira bug tracker of Embarcadero about TFDConnection. I move to Delphi 10.2 Update 1 and it works fine.. thanks